# openCV CvSVM::save generates too large file for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, opencv, svm

I use openCV. I've trained SVM, but the output file is too large (after svm.save()). I want to use trained SVM in iPhone's application, but the file is about 300 Mb. File's size after archive is about 6 Mb.

So, my questions:

1) Can I extract the archive with bzip2 when iPhone application starts and then use this file with SVM::load ?

2) Can CvSVM's save/load methods work with binary formats?

3) Do I need all information from output file to do a prediction?

4) Does a better solution exist for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to save svm object with bzip library (if it is possible, I don't know this library) and try to load the object with bzip afterwards to memory and for example use a pointer to it. `CvSVM.load()` generates xml file with support vectors and some additional data. I don't know if any of it is optional, but I doubt it.